# Formating a date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I want to show today's date plus 3 days.

I can do this with the following code:

```
    var newDt = new Date();
    newDt.setDate(newDt.getDate()+2);
    document.writeln(newDt);
```

This works well and outputs:

```
Thu Jan 03 2019 18:39:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

I, however would like to format the date as "Day, Month, Year" without any  additional time included.

I know there are various libraries that can do this, but is there a way to do it without?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: The lazy approach would be something like moment.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) method and specify `en-GB` as the locale to return the date in the *British English* date format of **day-month-year** order like this:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("date");

var y  = new Date();
y.setDate(y.getDate() + 3);

var z = y.toLocaleDateString("en-GB");

x.innerHTML = `The date is: ${z}`;
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

You can check the **`toLocaleDateString` [documentation here()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)** or check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/7380613) on another SO thread to see how you can add *options* to further customise the date format.

Answer (score 1):

There is no format string. The only way is to pull the data points one by one

```
date.getDate() + ', ' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + ', ' +  date.getFullYear()
```